# What does git [master +2 ~1 -0 !] mean?

Tags: git, powershell

I'm using the "Github For Windows" shell and was trying to commit something and came across what looks like an error:

```
C:\Path\Name\ [master +2 ~1 -0 !]>
```

What does `+2 ~1 -0 !` mean?

NOTE: I fixed the error by modifing every file in the directory and re commiting and pushing, now it's just `[master]`, but I still don't understand the numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not an error, just some helpful information.

I suppose you are using `Github For Windows` - it uses [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/) by default, and the prompt is explained in the README of `posh-git` itself:

```
+ = Added files
~ = Modified files
- = Removed files
! = Conflicted files
```

Go through the README and you can see how it relates to the `git status` output.

Comment: is it possible to configure other clients like [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) to include this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

**That *prompt* probably meant:**
 In your current git branch - `master`, you had added two files `+2`, modified one `~1` and removed zero `-0`.
<s>`!` signifies you are currently at the root of the repository.</s> *Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028432/29096) for more info.*

Not sure which *shell* you are using - But you may want to check the `PROMPT` and `PS1` *environment variables* to find what those items mean in your prompt.

The *prompt* got reset to just `[master]` - once you had committed all the changes, as you mentioned in your questions.

[`PROMPT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) environment variable is the one used by the windows shell `cmd`, and [`PS1`](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html) is used by *unixy* shells - like bash.

**Edit:** Totally missed the `powershell` tag you put in there - I'm not a windows guy - but looks like in *powershell* you create a `prompt` function - check this link: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/05/12/customizing-the-powershell-command-prompt/